# Non-sliding TabLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, tabs, android-tablayout

I am currently rewriting one of my iOS apps for Android, and I am working on adding tabbed navigation. The problem is, I haven't found a way to integrate tabs into an Android app without them being sliding (swipe left and right to switch tabs).

In the iOS version of my app, the middle of the three tabs contains a full-screen map view, so obviously in Android with the sliding tabs, the middle tab would not be slidable. I don't want this, as I would like to maintain consistency between the tabs.

Is there a way to deactivate the sliding on tabs? Or is there a way I could intercept the gesture in a similar way to the way a map would absorb it?

Answer (score 0):

> so obviously in Android with the sliding tabs, the middle tab would not be slidable

Actually, by default, it would be swipeable, though this would mean that the user cannot pan around the map. You have to take special steps to make a `MapView` get the touch events instead of the `ViewPager`, for reasons I have never fully understood.

> I haven't found a way to integrate tabs into an Android app without them being sliding (swipe left and right to switch tabs)

Use `FragmentTabHost`. Or, use `TabHost`. Or, write your own tab implementation that toggles the visible view or fragment.

Note, though, that your *users* may expect to be able to swipe between tabs, if the tab content itself is not something that obviously would take precedence (e.g., the map). Users may prefer that your app be consistent with other Android apps, rather than be consistent with an app (your iOS app) that none of them use.